# How can I get HTML elements by class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to manipulate the HTML through `getElementsByClass()` but for some reason it doesn't work. When I use `document.getElementByID()` it works? Why is this?

```
<div class='boldStuff'> <p>Welcome to the site. </p> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementsByClass('boldStuff').innerHTML = 'Fred Flinstone';
</script>
```

Comment: Just an aside: it's "Flintstone", not "Flinstone"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('boldStuff')[0]
```

Comment: @Michael is there anything else that can get the class being universally supported?

Comment: This is true, you have to do some error checking or just use jQuery.

Comment: It isn't even available in IE 8.

Comment: Also, it returns an array so you have to choose the first element.

Comment: @user172071 For good support you need a custom function or use a library. See related search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=getelementsbyclassname

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList. you will have to use

`document.getElementsByClassName('boldStuff')[0].innerHTML`

refer the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) at mdn

Answer (score 2):

Here's a widely supported solution:

```
function getElementsByClassName( root, clss ) {

    var result = [], els, i;

    if( arguments.length < 2 || !root || !clss || root.nodeType !== 1 ) {
        return result;
    }

    clss = clss + '';

    if( root.getElementsByClassName ) {
        result = root.getElementsByClassName( clss );
    } else if( root.querySelectorAll ) {
        result = root.querySelectorAll( '.' + clss );
    } else {
        els = root.getElementsByTagName('*');
        clss = " " + clss + " ";
        for( i = 0; i < els.length; ++i ) {
            if( ( " " + els[ i ].className + " " ).indexOf( clss ) !== -1 ) {
                result.push( els[ i ] );
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var bold = getElementsByClassName( document, "boldStuff" );

for( var i = 0; i < bold.length; ++i ) {
    bold[ i ].innerHTML = 'Fred Flinstone';
}
```

---

The benefit to this is that it uses the native methods wherever possible.

- It first tries `getElementsByClassName` because it is generally fastest.
- Then it tries `querySelectorAll`, which will bring in support for `IE8`.
- Finally, it does a manual filtering of all elements under the provided root.

Comment: Very good code snippet. But, [document's node type is 9.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp#nodetypes) You could remove condition `root.nodeType !== 1`.

Answer (score 1):

It returns an array so set the first element of the array's innerHTML

```
document.getElementsByClassName('boldStuff')[0].innerHTML = 'Fred Flinstone';
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct method to call is `getElementsByClassName()`, and it will give you an array of elements.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('boldStuff')
```

Anyway this is not compatible with older IE version. Check the compatibility [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11).

Comment: I am pretty sure this only works in Firefox, no? It has been awhile since I've used it - is this supported in all browsers now?

Comment: It doesn't work on IE up to 8, only since IE9 it seems to work.

Comment: @Michael exactly what I said.

Comment: @JoseFaeti, yes as I was typing it. You got to the post button first :)