# Is there a way to get an element by its class name using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to get an element by its class name using JavaScript?

Can I just use something like document.getElementByClassName('myClass') ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get HTML elements by class in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273338/how-can-i-get-html-elements-by-class-in-javascript)

Comment: Aha... getElements with an 's'! I suppose that makes since given that many elements may have the same class name.

Comment: NOT A DUPLICATE, THILO. That question did not have my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, there is such a thing as [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) and here's a [browser support list](http://caniuse.com/#search=getelements) which pretty much says "All recent browsers except IE8 and below"

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
```

also, there is [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) which uses CSS selectors. It's pretty much similar to how jQuery does it. [Here's a browser support list](http://caniuse.com/#search=queryse) of it, which also says "All recent browsers except IE7 and below"

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.myClass');
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed the 's' in my guess!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer jQuery. Try it:

```
var elements = jQuery(".myClass");
```

This will collect all elements with class = "myClass". If you want iterate and do some thing with this elements:

```
jQuery(".myClass").each( function() {
    // Getting element:
    var element = jQuery(this);

    doSomeStuff(element)
});
```