# Firefox, IE Opera -- function not defined

Tags: javascript

`DoRowApp` function is not defined in FF, IE, Opera. Works  in Chrome.

```
function DoRowApp(id) {
document.getElementById('ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.1.').value = id;
document.getElementById('ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.2.').click();
return true;}
```

This is the html

```
<a target="_blank" href="javascript:DoRowApp("_40558067");" title="Application Form"><img border="0"></a>
```

which we are getting from xml

```
<cell>Application Form^javascript:DoRowApp("'||edit.mhd_code||'");^_blank</cell></row>
```

As always..help would be awesome.

At the same time this function works:

```
function DoRow(id) {
'use strict';
var LowerBound, UpperBound, StartAppNo, BaseAppNo, i;
LowerBound = mygrid.getRowIndex(id) - 25;
UpperBound = mygrid.getRowIndex(id) + 100;
StartAppNo = 25;
BaseAppNo  = 0;
mygrid.selectRowById(id, true, true, false);
localStorage.clear();
if (mygrid.getRowIndex(id) - 25 > 0) {
    StartAppNo =  25;
}
else {
        StartAppNo =  mygrid.getRowIndex(id);
    }
localStorage.setItem("9999", StartAppNo);
if (LowerBound < 0) {LowerBound = 0; }
for (i = LowerBound; i <= UpperBound; i++) {
    if (mygrid.getRowId(i)) {
        localStorage.setItem(BaseAppNo, mygrid.getRowId(i));
        BaseAppNo++;
    }
}
document.getElementById('ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.1.').value = id;
document.getElementById('ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.2.').click();
return true;}
```

And the HTML for this is

```
<a target="_blank" href="javascript:DoRow("_40558067");" title="Application Form"><img border="0"></a>
```

Comment: I ***highly*** suggest you use event handlers instead of `javascript:`  in the `href`.

Comment: My installation of Chrome is up to date, and it doesn't have that function.

Comment: Why don't you just trigger the fonction on the `onclick` event of the link and then call `preventDefault()` so it  prevents default behavior of the element when clicked?

Comment: `href="javascript:DoRow("_40558067");"` is invalid quoted. you can either do `"'"` or `'"'` - see how the syntax highlighter colorized your html.

Comment: @metadings: Or `href="javascript:DoRowApp(&quot;_40558067&quot;);"`

Comment: @Bergi yeah but well, it's an ugly one ;) i also suggest you following @Rocket's comment, to move the `javascript:` out to a script tag based event handling code. to maintain the `_40558067`, that data should be moved to an attribute like `data-rowid` or whatever it is. @19eggs: can you change the xml source?

Comment: @Metadings: Yes, I can. Changed it to <cell>Application Form^onclick"DoRowApp("'||edit.mhd_code||'")";^_blank</cell></row> but it does not seem to work...

Comment: Hi! All, Looks like it is because of _blank in the xml. If I change to _self it opens in the same page. I would like to open in a different page. Any work around ? And thanks for all your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to let the javaScript out of your xml:

```
<cell>Application Form^'||edit.mhd_code||'</cell>
```

Or even better

```
<cell rowId="'||edit.mhd_code||'">Application Form</cell>
```

Then you produce the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="RowButton" data-rowId="_40558067" title="Application Form"><img border="0"></a>
```

Now you can add the event handler generic in javaScript:

```
function DoRowApp (rowId) { /**/ }

// Simplified onLoad
window.onload = function () {

    // Enum all elements with class="RowButton"
    var rowButtons = document.getElementByClassName("RowButton");
    for (var i = 0; i < rowButtons.length; i++) {

        // Closure for i and rowButton
        (function (i, rowButton) {

            // get the data-rowId attribute
            var rowId = rowButton.getAttribute("data-rowId");

            // Simplified addEventHandlerListener
            rowButton.onclick = function () {

                // call your function
                DoRowApp(rowId);

                // return false to prevent a href
                return false;
            };

        })(i, rowButton[i]); 
    }
};
```

I don't see where you are "opening" another webpage; in javaScript redirecting to another page is

```
window.location.href = "url";
```

To ensure it's the top-most frame, use

```
window.top.location.href = "url";
```

To open a new window, use [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open)

```
window.open(url, "_blank");
```

Further readings

- [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)
- [How can I get HTML elements by class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273338/how-can-i-get-html-elements-by-class-in-javascript)
- [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)
- [When and why to 'return false' in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855360/when-and-why-to-return-false-in-javascript)
- [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

As you see, to have a solid base to write cross-browser javaScript code, it is highly recommendable to use jQuery. The only other way to write simple javaScript is to only use latest browser versions - but how to tell that the users...

In jQuery the above would look like:

```
$(function () {  // simplified jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    // Enum all elements class="RowButton" and add click handler
    $(".RowButton").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Call your function
        DoRowApp($(this).attr("data-rowId"));

    });

});
```

As it looks like you're javaScript starter, I have the urge you to not use w3schools, read why on http://w3fools.com ! Better read

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript
- and for jQuery http://api.jquery.com