# Onload display div, change toggle element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a sample [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4Lb4t6p/5/) to demonstrate my issue.

I am using the following function to open div `#bogtoggle1` only on onload:

```
window.onload = function () {
 document.getElementById("node1").style.display = "block";
```

However, as a relative JS newbie, I can't quite figure out how to also get my toggle arrow (►`&#9658;`) on `#bogtoggle1` div to change to (▼`&#9660;`) on onload, as it does onclick.

Can someone help? Thanks

(FYI, THE JSFIDDLE HTML IS STATIC FOR DEMO ONLY, BUT POPULATES DYNAMICALLY FROM A DATABASE ON THE REAL SITE. The right-facing toggle arrow (►`&#9658;`) is what the inline style for the div defaults to. So I need a solution from within the function, not the HTML.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html header to this:

```
     <h2 id="Border" style="display:inline;cursor:pointer;"><a onclick="toggle(this, 'node1')"> Border <span style="font-size:1.1em;color:#5C6467;">&#9660;</span></a></h2>
```

i.e. make it be the "down arrow" `&#9660` by default, instead of the "side arrow" `&#9658`. This way, from then on, your `toggle` function will take care of the rest.

Here's an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urfatty/zvv83L3u/) based on your original.

---

*EDIT*

Based on the updated questions, here's a solution: give the `<span>` an `id`, then change the `innerHTML` of that `<span>` in the onload() function. See [the updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urfatty/zvv83L3u/1/).

HTML was changed to this (innerHTML as normal, but add `id` tag to the `span`):

```
<h2 id="Border" style="display:inline;cursor:pointer;"><a onclick="toggle(this, 'node1')"> Border <span style="font-size:1.1em;color:#5C6467;" id="theSpan">&#9658;</span></a></h2
```

JS was changed to this (add the second line to change to "down arrow" on load):

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("node1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("theSpan").innerHTML = '&#9660';
}
```

Comment: My apologies, please see the disclaimer in my re-edit.

Comment: no worries, check the edit and see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: So simple and exactly what I needed. Thanks! :3

Comment: My apologies again, will this work with getElementByClassName? Using an ID invalidates my page.

Comment: This will work, use `document.getElementsByClassName('someID')[0]`. Be careful though. (1) make sure you don't use that same class name for any other element. (2) the function 'getElementsByClassName` is not universally supported, for example in IE (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273338/how-can-i-get-html-elements-by-class-in-javascript).

Comment: just wondering, why would adding an `id` break the page, but adding a `class` is okay? I've never heard of such a situation.

Comment: Not sure, I only know I got 11 warnings for invalid markup using ID, whereas I don't have any using class.